# Can salt be used to create a slip resistance surface in concrete?

Tags: repair, concrete, deck, pool

Is it true that salt can be used to put a slip resistant surface in fresh concrete?

Comment: Salt, in general, is bad for concrete.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think you'd want to use salt for a couple of reasons:

- if you have any rebar in there, salt will increase corrosion
- salt will affect the concrete mix, possibly badly affecting strength

Instead, use one of the polymer grip additives designed for this purpose - they can be very cheap, and some are transparent so do not affect the appearance of the concrete.

An [example](http://www.concretecamouflage.com/pd_clear_grip_traction_32.cfm) - I haven't used this one, but there are many available.

Answer (score 4):

Many people seem to assume Jack was talking about mixing salt into the concrete but I believe he had been told about salt finished concrete. I used this in my new driveway and love the look but of course it is a matter of taste and style.

http://www.concretenetwork.com/rock-salt-finish/

If slip resistant is the most important parameter, I would recommend a broom finish.

http://www.concretenetwork.com/slip-resistant-coatings/broom-finish.html